# How to get the color attributes of command line text

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am making a game (a command line game, don't kill me) and I was adding a certain something to check the colour of command line text, then summing it by whatever bg color I wanted to have (bg colour is colour*16) to create a crude "pointing" system,

The problem is: How do I get a character from a grid (of text) which gets selectively chosen, then read it's colour, which is used to give that character a background different that the others?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

enum Color { DARKBLUE = 1, DARKGREEN, DARKTEAL, DARKRED, 
             DARKPINK, DARKYELLOW, GRAY, DARKGRAY, BLUE, 
             GREEN, TEAL, RED, PINK, YELLOW, WHITE};
void SetColor(int c){
    HANDLE hCon = NULL;

        if (hCon == NULL){
            hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hCon, c);
    }
}

void AdvSetColor(Color back,Color fore){
    int c;
    c = back * 16 + fore;
    SetColor(c);
}

char sometext[10][10] ={
    {"Lorem ipsum"},
    {"dolor sit am"},
    {"et, consect"},
    {"etur adipis"},
    {"icing elit,"},
    {"sed do eiusm"},
    {"od tempor inc"},
    {"ididunt ut l"},
    {"abore et dol"},
    {"ore magna al"}, //highlight all the words that are broken inbetween the sets
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your entire program, can you isolate the problem in a short example?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I think [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be able to do it. The annoying part is that you would have to play with the flags to get your color. There is also an [ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) version.

Comment: `ReadConsoleOutput` lets you read character and attribute information from specific points on screen. Though a better solution is to keep track of this state from within your program. Reading from the screen is generally a bad idea, because the user can mess with your screen, or other programs may print to it.